# Area of a triangulation of a non-planar polygon

Tags: geometry, area

Does the area of a triangulated simple non-planar polygon in 3D space depend on the triangulation, or is it the same for any triangulation of the points?

I would suppose it is not the same, but when I try to come up with simple examples it looks like it's the same for symmetry reasons. What is a counter example, or is the area constant for any possible triangulation?

Comment: The area of a non-planar shape is not defined.

Comment: "for symmetry reasons": what symmetry ?

Comment: Yes, but I can define the area of the triangulation as the sum of the triangle areas. For my problem only this sum matters.

Comment: Have you tried a single example ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought for example about a quad and flipping the diagonal and what may happen when I do this iteratively in the mesh.

Comment: And what does this example say ?

Comment: I think it has a symmetry there. One time you have for example a convex kink and the other time a flipped concave kink, but the differences should be the same. I didn't test it numerically, because I suppose there is some nice theoretical solution, probably for not all triangulations of all polygons having the same area, but I do not know how to argument this.

Comment: Try a single numerical example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two equilateral triangles with a common edge and unit area. If you change the angle they form, the total surface remains $2$. At the same time, the area formed by joining the other diagonal varies between $0$ and $2$.